# Execute a command on a remote server using php

Tags: php, ssh, ftp

I need to execute this command in my php project, first need to the document access.log and show it, then filter for the next code:

```
cat access.log |grep "2013-10-09" |grep Receive |grep from |grep 8386|wc -l
```

I know i need to stablish a connection to an SSH service but I don't know how to execute the command to go to the access.log and open it. I really need your help!

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are welcome to become familiar with `ssh2_connect()`, `ssh2_exec()` and all `ssh2_` function family.

Try here:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-connect.php
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-exec.php